# Is the following mappings automorphisms of their respective groups? (Herstein BOOK)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Is the following map an automorphism of the cyclic group $G$ of order $12$ ?
>   $$T : x \rightarrow  x^3 $$

My attempt :

I thinks the answer is  yes, because $G$ is cyclic, 
   $$T(xy) =  (xy)^ 3= x^3y^3 =T(x)T(y)$$ So $T$  is  a  homomorphism

Also   $T$ is  one -one as $T(x) = T(y) $ implies $x=y$

Is my  logic   correct or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3573190/403337.  Possibly a classmate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $T$ is a homomorphism, but that's because $G$ is Abelian, which implies that $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$. And, no, it is not an automorphism. If $G=\langle a\rangle$, then $(a^4)^3=(a^8)^3$, but $a^4\neq a^8$.

Comment: what  is $a$ here ??   im not  getting ?? i mean  what is the value  of a  ??

Comment: The element $a$ is a generator of $G$. So, $a^{12}=e_G$ and the smallest natural $n$ such that $a^n=e_G$ is $n=12$.

Comment: oks  i got its  thanks  u@ jose sir

Answer (score 3):

It isn't an automorphism. $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group of order 12. With your transformation you get $T(0)=0$ and $T(4)=0$ so it's not one to one.

Comment: how  T(4)  = 0 ?? @ Mark  can u  exaplain more

Comment: T(4)=4+4+4=12, and 12 equals to 0 in the group $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: oks  thanks  @Marks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\langle a \rangle$.  $T$ is not an automorphism of $G$ since there is no $x \in G$ s.t. $T(x)=a^5$. That is, if $x = a^i$ for some integer $i$, then $T(x) = a^{3i}$. So $a^{3i}=a^5$, but there is no integer $i$ for this to be possible. So $T$ is not onto, hence, not an automorphism.

Comment: Remember, it is not enough to say there's no $i$ such that $3i=5$.  You need the somewhat more difficult, no $x,y$ such that $3x+12y=5$.  But, in fact, any linear combination of $3$ and $12$ will be divisible by $3$.  So this is indeed impossible.  If, on the other hand, we replace $12$ by $n$ where $\operatorname{gcd}(3,n)=1$, the argument doesn't work.